# rich:extendedDataTable custom css

Tags: css, richfaces, seam

I'm using seam 2.3 with jboss AS 7 and i want to resize rows in rich extendedDataTable.
I see the inputTextarea like a classic inpuText.In many forum, people says that we have to change the css. I have had this css but in dont see any change...

```
<style type="css"> 
.autoSizeRows .rf-edt-hdr-c{
border-right:none !important;
border-bottom:none !important;
}
.autoSizeRows .rf-edt-c{
height: 100% !important;
border-right:none !important;
border-bottom:none !important;
}

.autoSizeRows .rf-edt-cnt td {
border-bottom: 1px solid #9FC0E9; 
border-right: 1px solid #9FC0E9;
}
</style>
```

with

```
<rich:extendedDataTable styleClass="autoSizeRows"  id="table" selectionMode="multiple" 
                value="#{BeanList.resultList}" rows="20"
          var="_bean"  frozenColumns="2" 
          selection="#{ClassAction.selection}" >
```

Thx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`height: 100%` doesn't really do anything for table cells. Just use a specific value - `height: 30px`.

Comment: Thx but no change. It is the good method ? How to do to see rows bigger ?

Comment: @Sebus It works for me, did you inspect the element to see why it's not working?

Comment: With firebug i can see my css class autoSizeRows: <div class="rf-edt autoSizeRows" id="form:table"> but i cant see the css

Comment: Ah, it should be `<style type="text/css">`

Comment: i have try this and add this css code into my file.css but no visual change :( thx

Comment: You should find a `.rf-edt-c` element, that one has the CSS, if it's not defined then something is wrong. You can try changing the height manually in firebug, if that isn't working then something is overriding it.

Comment: <style> must be into <ui:define> and it works :) but into my css file, i think it is overridden by a richfaces css file